# How to resolve this error in a Karma unit test, running on Jenkins: "Can't find variable: jQuery"

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jenkins, jquery-ui, bower

I have added the [ui-sortable](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-sortable/) library to an AngularJS project, to implement drag and drop functionality on an unordered list. The project uses bower to manage the UI libraries, and bower.json includes both jquery and jquery-ui

```
{
  "name": "fountain-inject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "jquery-ui": "1.12.1",
    "angular": "1.7.9"
  }
}
```

When this is built locally on Windows all the unit tests pass, but when built in Jenkins on Linux all then unit tests pass, but then this error is reported, and the build fails

```
[INFO] PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
[INFO]   An error was thrown in afterAll
[INFO]   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
[INFO]   bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:14
[INFO] PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 741 of 742 (skipped 1) ERROR (13.945 secs / 13.232 secs)
```

The build itself is the frontend module of a multi-module maven project. It uses the [frontend maven plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to install node, pull the bower and node dependencies, then run a gulp build file, including the unit tests

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v12.13.1</nodeVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>bower install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>bower</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>gulp build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>gulp</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>build</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>gulp test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>gulp</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>test --no-notification</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Don't you just need to `bower install` on the build server?

Comment: question updated with maven pom, including bower install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the was resolved when I added the bower_components/jQuery directory to the repository, and the build completed. For some reason, the build machine is having issues retrieve bower dependencies from the internet, but has no issues with the node dependencies needed for the build itself.